# G-WAN for Rapsberry Pi3?

Tags: linux, 32-bit, g-wan

This question is for the G-WAN development team.

I know that you've discontinued G-WAN 32-bit due to the very low demand of G-WAN for the Linux 32-bit platform.

But, with regard to both the worldwide success of the Rapsberry low cost computer and the very low footprint of the G-WAN web applicaton server, does the G-WAN folks plan to make a G-WAN release (for now, only in 32-bit but sooner than later for 64-bit for this computer) that could be used on the last Rapsberry Pi3 machine (using an ARM CPU) and running the Raspbian OS?

TIA for your (Gil) answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's a directed at an extremely specific, small group of people, and cannot be answered by the general population of this site.

Comment: @duskwuff: Dear, with regard to both the worldwide number of Rapsberry "Linux-like" users with the Rapsbian OS and almost the same amount of worldwide users of G-WAN (whatever the Linux distribution), your vote is, at a minimum, a charge against Rapsberry or G-WAN, and I'm sure you don't even use one of these two wonderful products. So, since a) the G-WAN development team respond here on stackoverflow, and b) obviously you're not one of these nice guys, please upvote your post and let the G-WAN folks respond. You are one against million users Worldwide. TIA.

Comment: @PCKB g-wan team mostly implement what they use themselves only... That is the case for 32-bit release I believe. So maybe if you can convince them that the Pi3 is worth their time ;)

Answer (score 1):

They are two incompatible platforms for the binary executable files so the fact that we discontinued the 32-bit release for `x86 CPUs` does not have relations with any release compiled for `ARM CPUs`, 32 or 64-bit.

G-WAN releases for other platforms than x86-AMD64 may come at a later stage but this greatly depends on business opportunities. For now a `VHDL port` is under progress.